# OMF file size for Mac to PC transfer

Tags: mac, pc, omf, file, transfer

Pretty soon I'll be starting audio post production on another feature film.  The video editor will be using FCP on a Mac and I use Nuendo on a PC.  Most of my work is for commercials and other short films/videos so when I get the OMF the file size is under 4gb.  In order to have a hard drive that can be read on both the Mac and PC it would have to be formatted in FAT32 (unless I'm wrong?).  But, the OMF will definitely be larger than 4gb with all of the audio info.  So, any suggestions on how to transfer this file between a Mac and PC?  Is there a different hard drive format that may work?  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Hey Matthew, 
If I'm not mistaken the file size limit for a single OMF is 2 gigs. 
This presents problems for people in production, but the easiest way to get around it is for the video editor to create multiple OMFs. 
Nuendo is a champ at opening many OMF's in the same project. 
I've worked with editors who have given me one OMF for each track of audio, and it works well. 
On the question of hard-drive compatibility, the easiest way for PC users to access mac hard-drives is to run a program called mac drive (http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/)
This of course requires a mac formatted hard-drive. So if you're investing in a new external hard-drive I'd suggest you partition your drive into two and have one half formatted on a mac computer. 
Then you can pull the OMF's off the mac editing computer, with out any problem. 
Then use mac drive to allow your pc to access the files on the mac partition. 
Hope that helps! 
-Kevin

Answer (score 2):

Hey Matt,

Regarding hard drive formatting, [check this question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/best-way-to-format-a-drive-for-sound). You definitally don't want to be formatting at FAT32 only, cause you can't transfer files larger than 4GB, and your video will be more than likely a lot bigger.

Yes, the limit for an OMF with consolidated media is 2GB. So you will need multiple ones. As @zenandtheart says, your editor can give them in sections and Nuendo will just bring all the separate OMFs into the same project.

Answer (score 2):

I use NTFS 3G (google it) to read b/w HFS+ on my macbook pro and my external NTFS. It's slow but it does the job. I like Kevin's idea of the dual partition however and I think that would be your best bet long term. Incidentally I've dual partitioned my macbook pro and installed Windows 7 on it and moving files between the 2 is easy as.

Answer (score 1):

hope the other post helped. Gd luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can now buy drives that are formatted to work with both MAC and PC.  They are more expensive, but in retrospect, I would have loved to spend the extra cash and have it be "plug-n-play" right out of the box.  I had PC, just like you, but had to format my drive on a MAC first.....which seemed backwards but, it was the only way it worked.  Even then, you still have to buy a program to allow both of the partitions of your drive to be readable by your PC.  Just my experience.